# MVC5 action method that returns a jsonresult works on my dev machine iperfectly but when deploy to iis i get 404 not found error

Tags: c#, jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `mvc5` action method that returns a `jsonresult` to a knockout `mvvm`.

On my development machine it works perfectly, but when I deploy to IIS, I get a 404 Not Found error.

When I used Google Chrome debugging tools, I get this message:

> //http:localhost/Student/Register_For_Courses not found

Below is my code:

**Controller Action**

```
public JsonResult Register_For_Courses()
        {
            ScoreService ss=new ScoreService();
            var courses = ss.FetchCoursesForSemesterRegistration().ToList();

            return this.Json(courses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**JavaScript file using Knockout**

```
function Course(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.CourseId = ko.observable(data.CourseId);
    self.CourseCode = ko.observable(data.CourseCode);
    self.Title = ko.observable(data.Title);
    self.CreditHour = ko.observable(data.CreditHour);
    self.Level = ko.observable(data.Level);
    self.Type = ko.observable(data.Type);

    self.SessionId = ko.observable(data.SessionId);
    self.SemesterId = ko.observable(data.SemesterId);
    self.StudentId = ko.observable(data.StudentId);

    self.ProgrammeCode = ko.observable(data.ProgrammeCode);
    self.Semester = ko.observable(data.Semester);
    self.IsOutStanding = ko.observable(data.IsOutStanding);

    self.result = ko.observableArray(data.result);
    return self;
}


//View Model
function CourseList(url) {
    var self = this;
    self.totalCreditHours = 0;
    self.courses = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.studentId = 0;
    self.semesterId = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'Student/Register_For_Courses',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (data) {
                self.courses.push(new Course(data));

            });

        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }

    });

    self.totalCreditHours = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.courses(), function (item) {
            var value = parseInt(item.CreditHour());

            total += value;
        })
        return total;
    },this);

    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new CourseList());
});
```

**MVC5 View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Students' Course Registration";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_StudentLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Semester Course Registrations</h4>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>
                            CourseCode
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Title
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Credit Hour
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            Type
                        </th>

                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: courses">
                    <tr>

                        <td data-bind="text:CourseCode"></td>
                         <td data-bind="text:Title"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text:CreditHour"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text:Type"></td>
                        <td data-bind="ifnot:IsOutStanding">
                            <button data-bind="click:removeCourse" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Total Units</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><b data-bind="text:tHour"></b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ViewModels/CourseRegistrationsVM.js")
}
```

Thank you for your kind and quick response.

Comment: you may try http:localhost/Your_Site/Student/Register_For_Courses

Comment: can you try this ?   url : "@(Url.Action("Student", "Register_For_Courses"))"